# Correct use of GROUP BY

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to say whether is entity from table `opportunities` upsell or not. One company can have multiple opportunities (1:N) and upsell is true when opportunity has a connection to a company and some other opportunity in the past has already finished business successfully (therefore `status` is 7) with the same company. Put in other words, first opportunity with status 7 is not upsell, all others with the same company are upsell regardless of their status.

So this is what I've tried

```
SELECT opportunities.id ,true as upsell FROM opportunities, (
  SELECT companies.id as company_id, opportunities.id as opportunity_id 
  FROM opportunities 
  JOIN companies ON companies.id = opportunities.company_id
  WHERE opportunities.status = 7
  GROUP BY companies.id, opportunities.id
  HAVING min(opportunities.created_at) = opportunities.created_at)
AS subs WHERE subs.opportunity_id = opportunities.id
```

Idea here is to select all first successfully finished opportunities (based on `created_at` column) in subselect and then remove them from all opportunities who has the same company. However even the subselect doesn't work correctly, it returns all opportunities filtered by `status = 7` so I've probably misunderstood the group by clause. 
 -

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want `opportunities` to be tagged as true when:

- the status = 7
- it is not the first record for the company

If so, I think this is much simpler:

```
select o.*,
       (row_number() over (partition by o.company_id, o.status
                           order by created_at
                          ) > 1 or
        status <> 7
       ) as upsell_flag
from opportunities o;
```

Comment: Looks correct, I am gonna test it more thoroughly now. Thanks a lot, partitioning is still magic to me :-/

Comment: Btw second condition is right but first is little different - the status of the first has to be 7 (the one which is tagged as false). Status of the rest doesn't matter. Upsell is true for all opportunities connected to the company after the first successful sell (status 7). It's about continuing business with someone with already positive record

Comment: Sorry for confusing you, I realized it's not easy to explain it :)